# Android USB device detection

Tags: android, usb, host

Since few days I am trying to solve some problem with my device communicating via USB with android 4.2.2 tablet. Attached device is USB-HID class device (which works correctly - tested under Windows and Linux). What is more, I try to test it on VirtualBOX android system and everything looks fine but with real android tablet attached usb device is not detected (no android usb enumeration?). I download USB Device Info from Play store which confirmed that no device is detected. But in different chart in USB Device Info application (called Linux) my device is recognized so it looks like android has some problems with proper detection attached device.
Does anyone know how to deal with that issue?

Comment: You forgot to include which android device you are dealing with. Regardless, USB host may not be fully implemented by all manufacturers, and is deliberately crippled by some.

Comment: Have you read: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/custom.html#connecting-over-usb

Comment: Yes I have read that sources, but instead of that I've got my own application that communicates over usb interrupt transfer mode. This mode is similar to keyboard/mouse that works correctly with my tablet. It is my own device (student project)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the issue.
I need to do following steps:

Connect over adb in root mode:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb usb
adb root
```

1) Copy edited file into sdcard 
    adb shell

```
# in shell terminal type:
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
# if necessary change /sdcard location to different one
cp /system/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml /sdcard
```

2) Open PC system file manager and find copied file (tablet_core_hardware.xml) in your sdcard. Open that file in text mode and add line (inside `<permissions>` ... `</permissions>` tags):

```
<permissions>
 ...
 <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
</permissions>
```

Save file and than in adb shell terminal (like in step 1.) type:

```
cp /sdcard/tablet_core_hardware.xml /system/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml
```

3) In shell mode (with su permission) type:

```
cd /system/etc/permissions/
touch android.hardware.usb.host.xml
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' >> android.hardware.usb.host.xml
echo '<permissions>' >> android.hardware.usb.host.xml
echo '<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host" />' >> android.hardware.usb.host.xml
echo '</permissions>' >> android.hardware.usb.host.xml
```

4) Check if both files contain proper content:

```
# instruction below should show just created file with its content
cat android.hardware.usb.host.xml
# check content of copied file (from step 2.)
cat tablet_core_hardware.xml

# if both files contain proper content type:
exit
exit
```

5) Reboot your Android device. After restart your device should have had full usb host mode (if it has got hardware USB-OTG interface).